# PDO inserts Japanese characters wrong in to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8, character-encoding

## Background

---

I'm currently writing a small web application for myself to test my Japanese. It consists of getting to see a Japanese word, and then giving the correct translation in Dutch. I have a small set-up where I can specify a Japanese word with the Dutch translation, and it will get inserted in the database.

## Problem

---

When inserting certain Japanese characters, such as "お" (or "O" for those wondering) it gets inserted in the database as "ず" (or "Zu"). There are more characters which also get transformed, but I forgot which (I cleared the database to see if certain solutions worked).

## What have I tried

---

I've made sure that all the things I think need to be `UTF-8` are set to `UTF-8`. I've set the following to `UTF-8`:

- HTML page header: 
  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
- PHP header (very first line): 
  `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
- The MySQL table `japanese_words`: 
   `ALTER TABLE japanese_words CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;`
- PDO encoding: 
  `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=japanese;charset=utf8', '****', '****');`
  And tried:
  `$db->exec("set names utf8");`

Specifying the Japanese word works in PHP. I can dump, and regularly show, the Japanese words in my webpage. This means my HTML and PHP are set up correctly. So there are no errors before inserting it in the database.

When I insert the Japanese words manually in the database it works.  
The characters get "transformed" when I try to insert it in to the database using `PDO`.

Trying to show the query `PDO` generates doesn't work. I get the query with the bound parameter and not the actual word.

## Code

---

`add_word.php` (this all works fine):

```
$japanese_word = $_POST['japanese_word'];
$dutch_word = $_POST['dutch_word'];

$word = new Word();
$word->setDutchWord($dutch_word);
$word->setJapaneseWord($japanese_word);

$wordDAO = new WordDAO($db);
$success = $wordDAO->addWord($word);
```

`WordDAO` method, where I think the problem is (or somewhere between there and the actual MySQL database):

```
$query = "insert into `japanese_words` (`word`) values(:word)";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':word', strtolower($word->getJapaneseWord()));
$stmt->execute();
$japanese_word_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
```

## Question

---

What am I doing wrong here? Did I forget to set up more encodings, or specify a particular PDO setting? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use `utf8_general_ci` for database collation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is I was using `strtolower()` in my `bindParam`. This changed the values of the Japanese words. Changing the code to the following worked:

```
$query = "insert into `japanese_words` (`word`) values(:word)";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':word', $word->getJapaneseWord());
$stmt->execute();
$japanese_word_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
```

Damn my blatant copy/pasting (of course I found out as soon as I posted the question).

Answer (score 1):

PDO

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=japanese;charset=utf8");
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");

$query = "insert into `japanese_words` (`word`) values(:word)";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);

// use mb_* function for japanese string 
$stmt->bindParam(':word', mb_strtolower($word->getJapaneseWord()));

$stmt->execute();

$japanese_word_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
```

Change Charset and Collation of a Database and Table

```
ALTER DATABASE japanese CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE japanese_words CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Set the charset of your page

```
<?php
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
...
```

You may have to check that your files are saved with the right charset!

Comment: Thanks for the extra additions, I have tried to apply them as best as possible. It was not the reason why it broke, but still give it a +1, because it was useful to me.